# How to make exponents in the SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, exponent

I found the new method in SwiftUI to allow you to create an exponent.

Here what I write code is based in SwiftUI on the Swift Playground.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct V: View {

    var body: some View { 

        HStack {

            Text("8")
            Text("2\n").font(Font.system(size: 10))

            }

        } 


}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(V())
```

The \n allows you to break the line and make a new line in UIKit. However, SwiftUI gives you to make a top while break line and make a new line inside the second Text. You can make a size for the Font in the Text.

[image]

That's it! You made the exponent in SwiftUI!

Comment: You seem to have provided an answer. You should edit your question so that it reads like a question, and then post a separate answer instead.

Answer (score 9):

The following seems look more naturally... as variant

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    Text("8") + Text("2").font(.system(.footnote))
                  .baselineOffset(UIFont.systemFontSize * 2 / 3)
}
```

Comment: using static func + (lhs: Text, rhs: Text) -> Text is the right way, not only looks better, but doesn't change the type of result.

Comment: The value in the `.baselineOffset` won't always be 10; it'll depend on the Text's font size.

Comment: @RPatel99, of course you're right, it is set for demo simplicity, and can be calculable in real project by needs, say `UIFont.systemFontSize * 2 / 3`, etc.

Comment: @Asperi , yeah, I just wanted to mention that because a lot of people copy-paste SO answers.