# SwiftUI Text - How to convert 10^12 to 10 the correct format

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am reading lines from a text files and displaying those lines on a Text element.

I may have scientific notation elements in there like

```
10^12 
10^9
```

etc...

I need to display that as

[image: 10^2]

[image: 10^9]

and these numbers are in the middle of phrases, like..

```
The universe has 10^12 bla bla bla
```

How can I do that?

I show no code because I am clueless on that one.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60232789/12299030? (of course you need to parse string at first to find needed pattern and then join back Text components).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of things are much easier in SwiftUI, there is lots of ways for this job in SwiftUI one of them could be this down code:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var yourFirstText: String = "The universe has "

@State var yourLastText: String = " bla bla bla"

var body: some View {

    Text(yourFirstText) + Text("10") + Text("12").font(Font.footnote).baselineOffset(6.0) + Text(yourLastText)


    }
}
```

Comment: This would require the OP to manually parse the text

Comment: @LeoDabus, hi Leo, You mean like defining some Var's or function to take text or numbers? if it is so it can be done if you think it is necessary

Comment: I mean a regex to find the ranges and properly format the text. Not so simple

Comment: similar to this post [How do you set a currency label to show smaller font size for cents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886403/2303865)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to first create a regex to find some digits separated by the `^` character `(\d+)(\^)(\d+)`. Then you would need to get the fourth range of the first match and change its baseline offset. Then get the third range delete its character:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var bindingManager = TextBindingManager(string: "The universe has 10^12 bla bla bla")
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            AttributedLabel(attributedString: bindingManager.attributedString)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

```
struct AttributedLabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    let attributedString: NSAttributedString
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { label.attributedText = attributedString }
        return label
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { uiView.attributedText = attributedString }
    }
}
```

---

```
class TextBindingManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var string: String
    var attributedString: NSAttributedString {
        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
        if let matches = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"(\d+)(\^)(\d+)"#)
            .matches(in: string,
                     range: .init(string.startIndex...,
                                  in: string)).first {
            if matches.numberOfRanges == 4 {
                mutableAttributedString.setAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10),.baselineOffset: 10],
                        range: matches.range(at: 3))
                mutableAttributedString.deleteCharacters(in: matches.range(at: 2))
            }
        }
        return mutableAttributedString
    }
    init(string: String) { self.string = string }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative Solution using `NSAttributedString`

Instead of using multiple `Text` compoments you could use just a single one and compose the text itself with `NSAttributedString`

```swift
let font: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 17)
let text = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string:"1012", attributes: [.font : font]
)
text.setAttributes(
    [.baselineOffset: 10, .font : font.withSize(10)],
    range: NSRange(location: 2, length: 2)
)
```

and then simply assign `attributedString` to your `UILabel`

```swift
yourLabel.attributedText = text
```

Since this answer does not apply to SwiftUI `Text` component directly, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59531265/8160613) to learn how to use UIKit `UILabel` inside your SwiftUI views.

Comment: @Ronnie: depending on choosing platform of coding make multiple answer possible like this one for UIKit, but the Future belongs to SwiftUI, if you want invest your time, just start with SwiftUI.

Comment: Let's not make it SwiftUI vs UIKit because both are great technologies and arguing which one is better is counterproductive. I am just supplying an alternative solution the first answer posted, not only of the OP but for anyone who finds this questions in the future.

Comment: @ witek: I am 100% agree with you and it is very nice we could find answers in SwiftUI and UIKit! good job!